# Internet connection lost when I close fiddler

Tags: windows-7, fiddler

I have installed fiddler on my local machine and when it's working for a long time it uses a lot of RAM.

I have internet when I'm using fiddler but when I close it, I lose my internet connection.

How do I switch off fiddler properly so that I don't lose my internet connection?

Comment: Without installing Fiddler on my machine, the obvious investigation that comes in my mind is "a" configuration in Fiddler that kills the internet. Could you kindly update your question to provide us with the status of your network rather than saying "It disappears"?

Comment: Please also include your operating system.

Answer (score 5):

#### I'm using fiddler but when I close it, I lose my internet connection.

`Fiddler` sometimes doesn't restore the Internet Proxy Settings when it is closed (it stays set to its own proxy, which is not longer running).

This means HTTP traffic will be sent to a proxy that doesn't exist.

---

#### "The proxy server isn't responding" Problem Caused by Fiddler

> Very occasionaly I ran into the problem of losing network connection
>   after using Fiddler for debugging with web traffic. To be more
>   precise, this problem usually happens after closing the Fiddler
>   application.
>
> ...
>
> After this problem happens, and when I open IE, I see the error
>   message of "The proxy server isn't responding".
>
> Fiddler sometimes fails to unregister itself as the system proxy upon
>   on quitting. In that case you will be redirecting all your HTTP
>   traffic to a proxy that doesn't exist, and thus gives you the error
>   shown above.
>
> The easy way to fix this, is to relaunch the Fiddler application which
>   will act as system proxy again (make sure you set the option in
>   "Fiddler Options" - "WinINET Connetions").
>
> Close the application gracefully and it should fix the connection path
>   for you.
>
> Or, you could manually clear the proxy settings by going to:
>
> `Internet -> Options` -> `LAN setting` -> `Connections`
>
> Uncheck the option of `Use a proxy server for your LAN`. (You should see a proxy
>   like 127.0.0.1:8888, which is the default listening port for Fiddler.)

Source [Fix "The proxy server isn't responding" Problem Caused by Fiddler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfang/archive/2012/07/18/fiddler-fix-quot-the-proxy-server-isn-t-responding-quot-problem-caused-by-fiddler.aspx)

Comment: Any way to make a script that unchecks the "Use automatic configuration script" option? 

I have these commands, but they don't really work:
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /f /D 0
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyServer /t REG_SZ /f /D ""... Well, I think they do remove the proxy setting, but the mentioned "automatic script" option is still there making the connections not work.